# Jailbroken iOS start and end call programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

Is it possible to programmatically start and end call in jailbroken iOS using Objective-C? I know that with non-jailbroken device it is not possible (especially call ending), but I'm asking for JAILBROKEN versions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE just because you are using the `xcode` IDE to develop doesn't mean you should be using it.

Comment: This question been answered many many times.

Comment: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CTCall, plus search creker's answers on Stack Overflow about the entitlements now required.

Answer (score 1):

To start a call use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1273183781414"]];
```

To end a Call just kill "Phone" application

```
 system("killall MobilePhone");
```

Comment: starting a call should work normally using openURL with `tel:12345a` urls, I guess. I'd add that to the answer

Comment: ah thanks, i will add now :) i thought it's so simple

Comment: Where to call system("killall Phone")? Is it possible to run code of my app during the call? I mean when call is active, my app is not responding untill end of call? Or there is a way to do it? I need to make app to start call and end it after 10 seconds.

Comment: And why do you need to do it that way on jailbroken phone when you have full access to all private APIs?

Comment: because my app should run always as service in background.

Comment: I'm saying that there are APIs for that `CTCallDial` and `CTCallDisconnect`. You don't need ugly hacks like in the answer above.